# Laravel can't upload file in storage folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-storage

I used to store my upload files (images) in my public folder but this time I want to store them in my storage folder and I get this error

```
Can't write image data to path (C:\laragon\www\mynewsite\storage\images/aboutimage-1522481830.png)
```

Error comes from this line (where I use [intervention/image](http://image.intervention.io/) package)

```
Image::make($image)->resize(1200, 600)->save($location);
```

My function:

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $filename = 'aboutimage' . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = storage_path('images/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image)->resize(1200, 600)->save($location);

        $oldFilename = $indexabout->image;
        $indexabout->image = $filename;
        Storage::delete($oldFilename);
}
```

any idea?

## UPDATE

My files will upload in `root/storage` folder instead of `root/storage/app/public/images`

why is that?

## Update 2

I changed my function to code below and it's uploading where it suppose to upload but `it does not delete the old image`

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $filename = '/aboutimage' . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = storage_path('app/public/images' . $filename);
            Image::make($image)->resize(1200, 600)->save($location);

            $oldFilename = $indexabout->image;
            $indexabout->image = $filename;
            Storage::delete($oldFilename);
}
```

Comment: Try this  `$location = storage_path('/images/' . $filename);`

Comment: @Nawin still upload in storage folder :/

Comment: What is your storage path returns and print your `$location` variable

Comment: how do i get what it prints?

Comment: gives me `C:\laragon\www\mynewsite\storage\imagesaboutimage-1522483434.png"`

Comment: Change your line like this `$filename = '\aboutimage' . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();`

Comment: @Nawin updated.

Comment: it will find the name of image from database and tell `Storage::delete(` which file is for delete.

Comment: You need to declare first this line `$indexabout->image = $filename;` not this line `$oldFilename = $indexabout->image;`

Comment: @Nawin Already, no difference.

Comment: echo Your `$oldFilename`

Comment: `aboutimage-1522485196.png` which is the `image` column in my db, so it has to delete and replace with new photo name.

Comment: So you need to delete the old file in db or folder?

Comment: @Nawin solved bro, thank you.

Comment: You are Welcome Bro :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SOLVED

here is final code:

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $filename = 'aboutimage' . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = storage_path('app/public/images/' . $filename); // root storage path
            Image::make($image)->resize(1200, 600)->save($location);

            Storage::delete('images/' . $indexabout->image); //public storage path
            $indexabout->image = $filename;            
        }
```

Basically I gave `Root/Storage` path to store data and `Public/Storage` path for deleting them in update method.